# Percentage of possible yards traveled?

Tags: statistics, nfl

How would one go about calculating their own NFL stats? For instance, I want to calculate the percentage total possible yards a team could have traveled if they had scored a TD on every drive.

Basically, total offensive yards / the sum of all (100 - starting field position)

Answer (score 3):

You need to find a useful source of data for your statistics.  [Pro-football-reference.com](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/) is a good one to start with.  They have a lot of different statistics available.

In your case, you could look at the box scores for individual games; see [this example](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201409220nyj.htm).  Towards the bottom are the drive statistics, which include all of the starting drive positions for both teams.

If you need help reading them in, post a question on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), or better yet look around for articles and instructions for doing so, which are plentiful.